# Change Project Namespace in Visual Studio for Mac Preview

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I very recently installed and playing with the Visual Studio for Mac Preview (NOT visual studio code).

I would like to rename the Project and thus the namespace. How can I do it? The solutions for Visual Studio for Windows either doesn't seem to work or I cannot find the proper menu item.

Thanks in advance,

Omer

Answer (score 1):

double click the project, `Project Options` -> `General` -> `Main Settings` -> right hand -> `Default Namespace`

but you cannot save it now, i got `Save failed.`